# sending VBA response of button press to C#

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I have a C# program that calls an Excel macro like this:

```csharp
private void _xlCall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
            Excels.Application oExcel = new Excels.Application();  
            Excels.Workbooks oBooks = oExcel.Workbooks;  
            string tabName=cbSelectTable.Text;  
            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;  
            Excels._Workbook oBook = null;  
            oExcel.Visible = false;  
string srcPath = "C:\\Desktop\\file.xlsm";  
oBook = oBooks.Open(srcPath, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);  
string fNames;  
                fNames = oExcel.Run(tabName);  
                oExcel.Visible = true;  
}
```

The Excel macro has a code that runs to do some formatting and then asks the user whether

> they want to update sql without looking at the data or would they want
>   to see the data first?

The VBA code is like this:

```vb
Sub checkDat(string tableN)  
//Update Code here  
.  
.  
.  
Dim Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt, Response, MyString  
Msg = "Do you want to insert the data to sql without viewing? "  
Style = vbYesNo     
Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style)  
Dim fkCntrl As IRibbonControl  
If Response = vbYes Then   
   XL2SQLInserts fkCntrl  
Else   
   MsgBox ("Data was not Inserted")   
End If  

Exit Sub  
error_wsconsol:  
MsgBox (Err.Source & ": The following error occured  " & Err.Description)  
End Sub
```

**Problem:**
I would like the Excel workbook to only open if the user clicks Yes.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Change your VBA Sub into a Function and return a value which your C# code can use?  But it looks like you're opening the file before you pop up the question?

Comment: What version of C# are you using? `oMissing` strikes me as useless/redundant/waaaaaaaaay-outdated.  ....also, what's up with all the Hungarian Notation?

Comment: @TimWilliams the oExcel.visible=true should be inside an if statement. Why do you say its opening the file before the pop up? oExcel.Run runs the VBA and then sends the popup and then nomatter what the Excel File opens up. Correct me if I am wrong here/

Comment: @Mat'sMug I am using VS 2012 Version 11.0.05. .Net Framework is 4.7.02 and C# version 5.0. I inherited this code so still working on it.

Comment: why ask that in a macro?  shouldn't you ask it in your C# code then open the workbook if a yes is selected.

Comment: I understood "I would like the Excel workbook to only open if the user clicks Yes" a bit more literally than you meant it maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it with the help of the people who commented here.
I changed the Sub to function like this:

```
Function checkDat() as String  
//Update Code here  
.  
.  
.  
Dim Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt, Response, MyString  
Msg = "Do you want to insert the data to sql without viewing? "  
Style = vbYesNo     
Response = MsgBox(Msg, Style)  
Dim fkCntrl As IRibbonControl  
If Response = vbYes Then   
   XL2SQLInserts fkCntrl
checkDat="Yes"  
Else   
   MsgBox ("Data was not Inserted")   
checkDat="No"
End If  

Exit Function
error_wsconsol:  
MsgBox (Err.Source & ": The following error occured  " & Err.Description)  
End Function
```

C# code is like this:

```
private void _xlCall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
            Excels.Application oExcel = new Excels.Application();  
            Excels.Workbooks oBooks = oExcel.Workbooks;  
            string tabName=cbSelectTable.Text;  
            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;  
            Excels._Workbook oBook = null;  
            oExcel.Visible = false;  
string srcPath = "C:\\Desktop\\file.xlsm";  
oBook = oBooks.Open(srcPath, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing, oMissing);  
string fNames;  
                fNames = oExcel.Run(tabName); //fNames is going to get the value   
if(fNames=="Yes")  
{  
                oExcel.Visible = true;    
}  
else  
{  
}  
}
```